# Projection of the dipole moment on the spherical unit vectors.

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

In his introduction to Electrodynamics, Griffiths wants us to prove what the electrostatic field of a dipole is like in a (he says) *"coordinate-free form"*. For convenience let's focus on proving the formula for spherical coordinates, independently of the position of the origin. This is purely a geometrical problem.

Let $\bf{p}$ be the vector corresponding to the dipole moment, and $\bf{r}$ the position vector determining the direction of the spherical unit vectors. Griffiths, citing this figure,

[image]

tells us that $\pmb{p} = p\cos \theta\ \pmb{\hat{r}} - p\sin \theta\ \pmb{\hat{\theta}}$, which is the key point of his argument, but to my eyes this is true only when $\pmb{p}$ is colinear to $\pmb{\hat{z}}$. In the rest of the cases, we should have 
$$\pmb{p} = p\cos \alpha\ \pmb{\hat{r}} - p\sin \alpha\ \pmb{\hat{\theta}} + p\cos \beta\ \pmb{\hat{\phi}}$$
with $\alpha := \angle \pmb{p\hat{r}}$ and $\beta := \angle \pmb{p\hat{\phi}}$.

Now the problem is that his reasoning fails with this last characterization of $\pmb{p}$. Am I wrong, or is his argument **not** coordinate-free? If I'm wrong, why?

Comment: Execuse me, but don't you think if ${\bf p}$ is aligned with ${\bf \hat z}$, then it's ${\theta}$ component should also be ${0}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you’re referring to the solution of Problem 3.36 (p. $160$ [here](https://ashirbadmohanty.files.wordpress.com/2018/09/introduction-to-electrodynamics-d-j-griffiths-4ed.pdf)) as provided on p. $73$ [here](https://physicaeducator.files.wordpress.com/2018/03/griffithssolutionsfull.pdf).

You’re right that this part of the derivation makes reference to a particular coordinate system and is thus itself not coordinate-free.

The task is not to derive the coordinate-free form without using coordinates. The task is only to show that the electric field *can be written* in a coordinate-free form. The solution does this by expressing the solution derived using spherical coordinates in a coordinate-free form, using only products and sums whose values are independent of the coordinate system. Since the field has a unique value, if it can be derived in a particular coordinate system and the result expressed in coordinate-free form, then this result is valid without reference to any coordinate system.

Comment: I don't get your answer: if I'm right for the general case, Griffiths is wrong: he was supposed to prove a statement valid for any coordinates system, not just for those where $\pmb{r}$ is parallel to $\pmb{\hat{z}}$. Obviously, what I mean is that I must be wrong somewhere, maybe in my interpretation of what he means by "coordinate-free form".

Comment: @toritoverdejo: I'm sorry, I had misunderstood the question. I'll edit to answer to answer the actual question.

Comment: @toritoverdejo: done.

Comment: I don't understand why, analytically, if he proves that a coordinate-free expression is correct in a coordinate-specific context, then it is correct in any case.

Comment: @toritoverdejo: I'm not sure what you mean by "case". There's no case here. Since the expression is coordinate-free, it's correct, period. It doesn't involve coordinates, so it makes no sense to ask whether it's correct for a certain coordinate system. Perhaps you're thinking of the dot product as the sum of the products of the coordinates of the factors. This is an expression for the dot product in orthonormal coordinates; but the dot product is an [inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) that exists independent of coordinates.

Comment: Ok, I see. Excuse me for the headache.

Comment: @toritoverdejo: No problem, that's what we're here for :-)